# Regex - How to ignore numbers that end with a comma

Tags: regex

I have been getting all the phrases that have numbers with words beside them by using this expression.

```
[\d+](?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,1}
```

Input:

> 50 cases are confirmed. 
>   On January 30, there are confirmed cases of the virus. 
>   1,300 women are suscpected.

Matches:

> **50 Men** are involved. 
>   On January **30, there** are confirmed cases of the virus. 
>   **1,300 women** are suscpected.

The problem is, there are cases where dates are involved, which I'm not interested in getting. So my expected output are actually just these two

Expected:

> **50 Men** are involved. 
>   On January 30, there are confirmed cases of the virus. 
>   **1,300 women** are suscpected.

How do I ignore the numbers that ends with commas?

I have tried doing the following expression by adding **,** to ignore but it just counts the numbers individually.

Attempt:

```
[\d+](?:[^a-zA-Z'-,]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,1}
```

Output:

> **50 Men** are involved. 
>   On January **3** **0**, there are confirmed cases of the virus. 
>   **1**,**300** women** are suscpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\d+(?:,\d+)?\s+[a-zA-Z]+`

Explanation:

`\d+` - match 1+ digits

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`,\d+` - match comma `,` and 1+ digits

`?` - match preceeidng pattern 0 or 1 time (`{0,1}` equivalent)

`\s+` - match 1+ whitespaces

`[a-zA-Z]+` - match 1+ lowercase or uppercase characters

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZigxYA/1)

Comment: here is a great tool for understanding regexp: https://regexper.com/#%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B%29%3F%5Cs%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B